# Keyword based JPA query with statuses as Enums and with NOT clause [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a Keyword based JPA query I need to modify in order to exclude records with a particular status. Currently, I have the following:

```
findAllByLatestVersion_Entity_DataFieldGreaterThanEqualAndLatestVersion_AnotherFieldNull(datefield: Istant, pageable: Pageable)
```

I do not want to parameterise, therefore I would like to have the query to work as there was a WHERE clause stating that the status IS NOT C, for example. I am struggling to find clear documentation on how to go about. Is it possible to write something along these lines:

```
findAllByLatestVersion_Entity_DataFieldGreaterThanEqualAndLatestVersion_AnotherFieldNullAndLatestVersion_StatusCNot(datefield: Istant, pageable: Pageable)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible with query derivation, i.e. the feature you are using here. And even if it were possible you shouldn't do it.
Query derivation is intended for simple queries where the name of the repository method that you would choose anyway perfectly expresses everything one needs to know about the query to generate it.
It is not intended as a replacement for JPQL or SQL.
It should never be used when the resulting method name isn't a good method name.

So just formulate the query as a JPQL query and use a `@Query` annotation to specify it.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion and I am also disturbed by the fact that such keyword queries tend to have very long method names and in the long run became difficult to maintain as well as a pain for new developers getting to know the codebase.